# Calinski-Harabasz score as a validity index for hierarchical clustering with distance matrix

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a distance matrix that I want to performed hierarchical clustering with, and find the optimal number of clusters by maximizing the Calinski-Harabasz (CH) score. However, I only know how to calculate the CH score when you have a (object x features) data. I am not sure how I could use a distance matrix to calculate the CH score. Is it possible? and do the distances have to be necessarily Euclidean for the CH score to be valid?

Any help is appreciated.